# How to draw lots of polygons quickly in pycairo?

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I have a function which draws polygons into a pycairo context like so:

```
def draw_polygon(context, polygon):
    context.move_to(*polygon[0])
    for point in polygon:
        context.line_to(*point)
    context.line_to(*polygon[0])
```

Then, this is called many times (~350k) by this loop:

```
for polygon in polygons:
    draw_polygon(context, polygon)
    context.stroke()
```

Running `cProfiler` on things, `draw_polygon` is the major bottleneck, taking up about 60% of `tottime`.

What's a good approach to optimizing this type of drawing when large amounts of geometry are involved? Is there way, similar to openGL, to assemble geometry into a vertex list or some other optimized data structure?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: I think you want `context.close_path()` instead of doing a `line_to` to the initial point in the end. Also, you can just do `context.new_sub_path()` and then the first following `line_to` is automatically turned into a `move_to`, so that you can also get rid of the first `move_to`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way, similar to openGL, to assemble geometry into a vertex list or some other optimized data structure?

There is `context.append_path()`. Internally, this just calls the other C functions and does nothing special, but perhaps it can save some overhead from pycairo? I'm not sure if this really would be faster.

However, the docs for `append_path` say the following, which makes me think that you cannot really construct this data structure from pure Python:

> Append the path onto the current path. The path may be either the return value from one of Context.copy_path() or Context.copy_path_flat() or it may be constructed manually (in C).